# Uncaught Error:cannot call methods prior to initialization;

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, bootbox

I m calling a form in a popup using bootbox

```
bootbox.alert(myform, function () {
  }).find("div.modal-dialog").addClass("largeWidth");
```

in the form there is a  a pallete collor picker(evol colorpicker)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#cd_bundle_entitiesbundle_call_Color").colorpicker();
 });
```

The first time the form popup opens the pallete for color pick displays ok but only for one time.
After that if i close the popup and open it again when pressing for the color pick pallete getting the error
Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on colorpicker prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'hidePalette'

Reading similar questions i think i ve to destroy the bootbox popup so in the callback of bootbox tried $(this).empty or $(this).remove() but didnt work

This is my form in a html file with some js

```
<div class="col-lg-6">

        {{ form_start(form, {'action': path('calls_edit_exec'),'attr': {'class': 'callform'} } ) }}
        <fieldset>

            {{ form_errors(form) }}
            <div class="row">
                <label class="col-md-3">Requestor</label>
                <label class="input col-md-5">{{ form_widget(form.Requestor) }}</label>
                <span id="inforeq" class="inforeq fade info  alert-success" ></span>

            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <label class="col-md-3">CallStatus</label>
                <label class="input col-md-5">{{ form_widget(form.CallStatus) }}</label>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <label class="col-md-3">Color</label>
                <label class="input col-md-5">{{ form_widget(form.Color) }}</label>
            </div>

            <span class="fade">
                <input id="mycolor" class="colorPicker evo-cp0" />
            </span>

            <div class="row">
                <label class="col-md-3">AssignedTo</label>
                <label class="input col-md-5">{{ form_widget(form.AssignedTo) }}</label>
                <span id="infouser" class="infouser fade info  alert-success" ></span>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <label class="col-md-3">Category</label>
                <label class="input col-md-5">{{ form_widget(form.CallCategory) }}</label>
                <span id="infouser" class="infouser fade info  alert-success" ></span>
            </div>

            <div class="row col-lg-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <label class="col-md-3">Call Problem</label>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <label class=" textarea col-md-12">{{ form_widget(form.CallProblem) }}</label>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <label class="col-md-3">Call Solution</label>
                </div>
                <div class="row" >
                    <label class="textarea col-md-12">{{ form_widget(form.CallSolution) }}</label>
                </div>
                <div class=" form-control">
                    <input class="form" type="checkbox" name="createready" id="createready">Make this Ready Call/Solution<br>
                </div>
            </div>

        </fieldset>
        {{ form_end(form) }}
    </div>
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function () { $("#cd_bundle_entitiesbundle_call_Color").colorpicker();
   }); </script>
```

With a click the the form is returned from an ajax call

```
$.ajax({
                                url: url,
                                success: function (data) {
                                    bootbox.alert(data, function () {

                                       // $this.empty();
                                    }).find("div.modal-dialog").addClass("largeWidth");

                                }
                            });
```

To get the form in popup i m using bootbox

Comment: It sounds like you may be deleting and recreating the colorpicker DIV dynamically. Every time you recreate it, you need to call `.colorpicker()` on the new element. Perhaps instead of deleting and recreating it, you should just hide and show it.

Comment: The first time the popup with the form pops the colorpicker initialise   $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#cd_bundle_entitiesbundle_call_Color").colorpicker();
 });

Comment: I understand that. That's why it works the first time. But you must be destroying it and then trying to call `hidePalette` on it after doing that, and that gets the error. You have to re-initialize the new colorpicker.

Comment: sorry the previus comment is incomplete  The first time the popup with the form pops the colorpicker initialise   $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#cd_bundle_entitiesbundle_call_Color").colorpicker();
 });  next times the form pops there is no colorpicker so i get the error.  i need to initialise it every time the the form pops but if i try it just before the bootbox call the div id does not exist by that time.

Comment: You need to show your HTML and more code. It's impossible to tell from your description what you're doing and where to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you're using this to load the modal with remote content:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    success: function (data) {
        bootbox.alert(data, function () {
           // $this.empty();
        }).find("div.modal-dialog").addClass("largeWidth");
    }
});
```

If so, I would use the [`show.bs.modal`](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events) method as the point where you trigger the colorpicker:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    success: function (data) {
        bootbox.alert({ 
            message: data, 
            callback: function () {
               // do something when dismissing the alert
            },
            className: 'largeWidth'
        })
        .on('show.bs.modal', function(){
            $("#cd_bundle_entitiesbundle_call_Color").colorpicker();
        });

    }
});
```

I've also tweaked your example to use an options object, as shown in the [documentation](http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html#bb-dialog-options).

It's worth noting that there are [size options](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-options) for Bootstrap modals as of 3.1.0, which you can apply as you were with your `largeWidth` class, or you can use the equivalent `size` option as noted in the Bootbox docs I linked to previously.

Comment: T thnx for the answer, with .on show.bs.modal the instance of colopicker is initialised every time the form pops but still getting the same error. The colorpicker initialise anyway everytime since the ready document func runs evrytime form pops.  I think has to do with colorpicker creates dynamic div ids for the pallete colors and there is some reference to them but the second time the form pops there other div ids..i tried $("#id).colorpicker(destory); and destroy all html after close the modal but still getting the error